# Posterior distribution as a distribution for a new random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

So in Bayesian framework one uses observed data $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ to update the prior $p(\theta)$. My question is it justified mathematically to say that $p(\theta\mid x_1,\dots,x_n)$ corresponds to a new random variable itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe that the prior can be represented by a random variable, then the assertion follows by Bayes' Theorem.  The difficult and controversial issue with the Bayesian framework is whether you believe that there is a prior distribution.  I happen to not believe in it.

Comment: So the existence of pdf according to Bayes' theorem is sufficient to claim that $p(\theta|x_1,...,x_n)$ is a pdf for a random variable. If so, can I go further and say that if my data is observed sequentially at each step, then I will get the random variables $\theta_0, theta_1,...,theta_n$, with pdfs $p(\theta), p(\theta|x_1),..., p(\theta|x_n)$ respectively?!

Comment: Of course, non-Bayesians often implicitly assume a prior distribution, though they often don't like that pointed out. More worrying perhaps is when an improper prior leads to a reasonable posterior.

Comment: @Marc You mean when they use maximum likelihood estimators.  Yes, I do agree.

Comment: @Naji You mean $\theta_k$ has pdf $p(\theta|x_1,\dots,x_k)$?  Either way, I think you are correct.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, but I didn't see the relation to discussion?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, and just one more question. Then I might even say that $theta_i$'s generate a markov chain, right?!

Comment: I don't think that $\theta_k$ necessarily satisfy the property of being "memory-less."

Comment: I do believe that is the case but can't prove it, based on the fact that $theta_n$ is an update on $\theta_{n-1}$ conditioned on the fact that the new data has been observed. So knowing the new data $x_n$ and $theta_{n-1}$ one is able to calculate $\theta_{n}$ with Bayes rule. This is the proof sketch I might say :D

Although thanks anyway.

Comment: @Naji I think you're right. All necessary information for $\theta_n$ is contained in $\mathbf{x}_n$ and $\theta_{n-1}$ so $\theta_n$ and $\theta_m$ are independent for $m<n-1$.

Comment: @Naji I thought a bit about it, and I think I agree with hejseb.

Comment: Just so there won't be no confusion: $\theta_n$ and $\theta_{n-2}, \theta_{n-3}, \dots$ are independent *conditional on $\mathbf{x}_n$ and $\theta_{n-1}$*. I somehow left the conditional part out of my comment...